# Haven not working for exporting SAS. SAS7bdat package not compatible with R version

Tags: sas, r-haven

I've been trying to import an SAS file with both Haven and sas7bdat. With the Haven package it gives me an error saying: "Failed to parse C:/Users/mtmol/Desktop/Wk1_Data.sas7bdat: Invalid file, or file has unsupported features." yet, I know there is nothing wrong with the file since it imports fine into Stata. I tried to install sasdbat but I get the following message:
"package ‘sas7dbat’ is not available for this version of R"

Not sure what else to do!

Comment: What version of R are you using?

Comment: I am using R version 4.1.1